# How to leave certain values (which have a comma in them) intact when separating list-values in strings in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

From the dataframe, I create a new dataframe, in which the values from the "Select activity" column contain lists, which I will split and transform into new rows. But there is a value: "Nothing, just walking", which I need to leave unchanged. Tell me, please, how can I do this?

The original dataframe looks like this:

```
    Name    Age   Select activity                 Profession
0   Ann     25    Cycling, Running                Saleswoman
1   Mark    30    Nothing, just walking           Manager
2   John    41    Cycling, Running, Swimming      Accountant
```

My code looks like this:

```
df_new = df.loc[:, ['Name', 'Age']]
df_new['Activity'] = df['Select activity'].str.split(', ')
df_new = df_new.explode('Activity').reset_index(drop=True)
```

I get this result:

```
    Name    Age   Activity
0   Ann     25    Cycling
1   Ann     25    Running
2   Mark    30    Nothing
3   Mark    30    just walking
4   John    41    Cycling
5   John    41    Running
6   John    41    Swimming
```

In order for the value "Nothing, just walking" not to be divided by 2 values, I added the following line:

```
if df['Select activity'].isin(['Nothing, just walking']) is False:
```

But it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then let's look ahead after comma to guarantee a Capital letter, and only then split. So instead of `,`  we have `, (?=[A-Z])`

```py
df_new = df.loc[:, ["Name", "Age"]]
df_new["Activity"] = df["Select activity"].str.split(", (?=[A-Z])")
df_new = df_new.explode("Activity", ignore_index=True)
```

i only changed the splitter, and `ignore_index=True` to `explode` instead of resetting afterwards (also the single quotes..)

to get

```py
>>> df_new

   Name  Age               Activity
0   Ann   25                Cycling
1   Ann   25                Running
2  Mark   30  Nothing, just walking
3  John   41                Cycling
4  John   41                Running
5  John   41               Swimming
```

---

one line as usual

```py
df_new = (df.loc[:, ["Name", "Age"]]
            .assign(Activity=df["Select activity"].str.split(", (?=[A-Z])"))
            .explode("Activity", ignore_index=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your version works if the next word after the comma starts with a small letter. For example, with the value "Mind and body (Yoga, Massage, etc.)" this will no longer work, and such a value will be split into 3 lines: "Mind and body (Yoga", "Massage" and "etc.)"

Comment: indeed. without a pattern this problem is impossible to solve programatically in an automatic manner. maybe they will say nlp etc but i don't know that. so if you have some patterns, there's a way; if not, i don't know what to do